# sh - Cron - Environment Variables

Tags: cron, websphere, sh

I'm trying use a System Script to verify the status of server, in past I implement something like check PID of process is running or not, but I think this is the best way, but I'm stucked to put this running on a Cron. I'll try to resume this as possible.

My Script

```
/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/bpm/bin/serverStatus.sh $server -username adm -password adm
```

System Script - serverStatus.sh

```
binDir=`dirname ${0}`
. ${binDir}/setupCmdLine.sh   # Here he set the env variables
${WAS_HOME}/bin/serverStatus.sh "$@" # Here he call the global script with
                                     # all env variables set to use the script
```

I don't want to change anything related to PATH because some variables of others scripts depends of the current path to use the WAS_HOME, anyway to solve this and put this on Cron.

thanks in advance
tiago

Comment: It's not clear from your description what the actual problem is.  Is the invocation of serverStatus failing in some way?  If yes, what error are you seeing?  If no, what's actually wrong?

Comment: Well, this only don't work on Cron, I think this is related to env variables

Comment: In what way does it "not work"?

Comment: the serverStatus.sh produces a log and this log don't had any entry at Cron  hour, and get stucked here, because I have another things next this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve the problem using:

/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin/serverStatus.sh -all -username adm -password adm